# Is the annihilator appearing in linear algebra books the same as the one of second quantization?

Tags: linear-algebra, second-quantization

I have seen in some linear algebra textbooks such as Hoffman & Kunze, Friedberg & Insel & Spence, or Advanced Linear algebra by Roman the definition of annihilator. Here I take the definition from Friedberg for a vector*:

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, 
>   and let $x$ be a nonzero vector in $V$. The polynomial $p(t)$ is called
>   a $T$-annihilator of $x$ if $p(t)$ is a monic polynomial of least degree
>   for which $p(T)(x) = 0$.

It is quite abstract so I am wondering if it corresponds, or has anything to do, with the annihilator used in second quantization. Wether the annihilator of second quantization is an extension when going to infinite dimensions or not. If the response is negative I would like to know wether there is a formal mathematical object behind it or it is a new construct that did not exist before in mathematics.

* There is also a definition for sets.

Comment: Which annihilator in qft are you talking about? Destruction operator? In a sense the annihilator of this operator is the vacuum state (in the Bargmann representation). But this is just a fancy way to label the constant function.

Comment: @lalala Destruction operator, I do not know others. Like the one that appears [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/365898/single-particle-operator-in-second-quantization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes, if we identity

- $T \leftrightarrow a$ with an annihilation operator;
- the vector space $V$ with an infinite-dimensional [Fock space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space);
- $x \leftrightarrow |\Omega \rangle$ with the vacuum state;
- and the polynomial $p\leftrightarrow {\rm Id}$ with the identity $t\mapsto t$.

Answer (score 1):

The linear algebra author is using the word annihilator in a very different sense from the use in field theory.

The "annihilator" in the linear algebra text is involved in the spectral decomposition of $T$:   If $x$ is annihilated by a linear polynomial, $(T-\lambda I)x=0$,  for example, then $x$ is an eigenvector of eigenvalue $\lambda$.  If $(T-\lambda I)^n x=0$, but $(T-\lambda I)^mx\ne 0$ for any $m<n$ then  $x$ is a *generalized eigenvector*. If $P(T)$ is the monic polynomial of lowest order that annihilates all $x\in V$ then $P(T)=0$   is usually called the "minimal polynomial equation" for $T$ If $P(t)$ has no repeated roots then $T$ is diagonalizable --- i.e. you can find sufficiently many  eigenvectors to form a basis for $V$.  If $P(t)$ has repeated roots, then the best you can do is reduce $T$ to its  Jordan canonical form ---  in which process the generalized eigenvectors  play a key role.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer? Do you mean the purpose of introducing the concept?

Comment: $Zythos. I have elaborated...